# show new products without special price

Tags: product, price

How to show new products without special price? Is it possible to do this in new.phtml

```
<?php if (($_products = $this->getProductCollection()) && $_products->getSize()): ?>

    <div class="newproducts">
        <div class="carousel">
            <div class="slider">
                <?php $i=0; foreach ($_products->getItems() as $_product): $i++; ?>

                    <!--<div class="item slide <?php //if(($i == 4 && $_products->getSize() < 5) || ($i == $_products->getSize()) ) echo 'last'?>">-->

                    <div class="item slide">
                        <?php include('view/labels.phtml')  ?>    
                        <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>

                        <!-- product -->
                        <div class="box-product-item">
                          <div class="view-first">
                            <div class="view-content">
                              <div class="image">
                                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">
                                    <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(188) ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
                                </a>
                              </div>
                              <div class="bottom-block">
                                <div class="name">
                                    <?php

                                    $shortenby = themeOptions('shorten_name');

                                    $product_name = $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName());

                                    mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

                                    //if(strlen($product_name) > $shortenby) { $product_name = mb_substr($product_name,0,$shortenby).'...'; }
                                   ?>
                                   <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $product_name ?></a>
                                </div>
                                <!--<div class="link-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php //echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"></div>-->
                                <div class="price">
                        <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--
                            <div class="slide-block">
                              <div class="image-rating"></div>
                              <div class="btn-wish" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToWishlistUrl($_product) ?>')"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wish List') ?></div>
                              <div class="btn-compare" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product) ?>')"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></div>
                            </div>
                            -->
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- / product -->

                    </div>
                    <?php if($i==10){break;}?>  <!-- limit number of display item -->
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>             
        </div>
        <?php //if($_products->getSize() > 1): ?>
            <!--<div class="prev new-arrow">&nbsp;</div>-->
            <!--<div class="next new-arrow">&nbsp;</div>-->
        <?php //endif; ?>
    </div>     
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <?php if($_products->getSize() > 1): ?>

        <!--
        <script type="text/javascript">

            jQuery('.new-arrow.prev').addClass('disabled');
            jQuery('.carousel').iosSlider({
                desktopClickDrag: true,
                snapToChildren: true,
                infiniteSlider: false,
                navNextSelector: '.new-arrow.next',
                navPrevSelector: '.new-arrow.prev',
                lastSlideOffset: 3,
                onFirstSlideComplete: function(){
                    jQuery('.new-arrow.prev').addClass('disabled');
                },
                onLastSlideComplete: function(){
                    jQuery('.new-arrow.next').addClass('disabled');
                },
                onSlideChange: function(){
                    jQuery('.new-arrow.prev').removeClass('disabled');
                    jQuery('.new-arrow.next').removeClass('disabled');
                }
            });


        </script>
        -->
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may resolve the issue, try by commenting the code.

Instead of this:

```
 <div class="price">
     <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
 </div>
```

Try This:

```
 <div class="price">
     <?php echo number_format($_product->getFinalPrice(),2);?> 
 </div>
```